# invalid from flag value basebuild: pull access denied for basebuild, repository does not exist or may require 'docker logi

Tags: linux, azure, docker, kubernetes, registry

I have built Docker image using below image file

```
FROM    centos:7 AS base

RUN     yum -y install libgomp && \
        yum clean all;


FROM        base AS build

WORKDIR     /tmp/workdir
RUN     buildDeps="autoconf \
                   automake \
                   bzip2 \
                   bzip2-devel \
                   cmake3 \
                   diffutils \
                   expat-devel \
                   file \
                   gcc \
                   gcc-c++ \
                   git \
                   gperf \
                   libtool \
                   libffi-devel \
                   make \
                   perl \
                   srt-libs \
                   openssl-devel \
                   readline-devel sqlite sqlite-devel openssl-devel xz xz-devel \
                   tar \
                   yasm
```

I built with below command

```
 docker build -t myacr.azurecr.io/buildimage:latest -f Dockerfile-extend .
```

Now I want to use build image and in another Docker image file

I tried like this

```
FROM myacr.azurecr.io/buildimage:latest
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64:/usr/local/lib

COPY --from=build /usr/local/ /usr/local/

#Copy code
COPY . /app/
WORKDIR /app
```

and I am getting below error:

```
docker build -t myacr.azurecr.io/app1:latest -f Dockerfile-extend .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  26.75MB
Step 1/9 : FROM myacr.azurecr.io/buildimage:latest
 ---> cc0b03a03c8b
Step 2/9 : ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64:/usr/local/lib
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 927e26c14864
Step 3/9 : COPY --from=basebuild /usr/local/ /usr/local/
invalid from flag value basebuild: pull access denied for basebuild, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

How to fix ?

Comment: Hello @Vidya, If my answer is helpful for you, you can Upvote and accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I did a change in your code and run in my environment.it is working for me. Please Use the below code.

```
FROM myacr.azurecr.io/buildimage:latest
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64:/usr/local/lib
COPY --from=myacr.azurecr.io/buildimage /usr/local/ /usr/local/
#Copy code
COPY . /app/
WORKDIR /app
```

[image]